# Is there a portable equivalent of gcc's __attribute__ (pure)?

Tags: c++, gcc, portability

I'm writing some code where there are a bunch of simple pure functions that get called a lot. It's perfectly safe if these functions get get optimized to be called less often.

Currently I am using gcc as my compiler and I'm wondering if there is a portable way of doing:

```
int foo(int) __attribute__ ((pure))
```

Info about the pure keyword can be found here:
http://www.ohse.de/uwe/articles/gcc-attributes.html#func-pure

How would I go about implementing something like this if the pure keyword is not available?

Comment: The description of pure functions reminds me of class static functions. Are they by any chance optimized in similar way with comparable performance?

Comment: @DmitryYudakov Class static function are not non number functions with a class scope. They have nothing special.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since C++11, you can use the [standardized attribute syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) with GCC specific attributes:

```
[[gnu::pure]]
int foo(int)
```

Since C++17, this is guaranteed to be fine on any compiler, since if they don't recognize `[[gnu::pure]]`, they must ignore it without error.

Comment: Interesting to see how much has changed in the last few years with C++ standards.

Comment: The painful thing about this is that most compilers warn on unrecognized attributes. I did place a bug in compiler vendors' ears that they shouldn't do so (at least for namespaces which they do not "own", e.g. GCC shouldn't warn for attributes of `[[clang::...]]`), but it'll probably be a while before it happens. Furthermore, MSVC has some attributes for which it has no C++11 standard attribute equivalent. In practice, this means that you'll generally be left with using the preprocessor to detect the compiler, `#define`ing a macro to be the appropriate attribute for the detected compiler.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is not.

Comment: :( I suspected this was the case.

Answer (score 5):

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define __pure __attribute__((pure))
#else
#define __pure
#endif
```

Use `__pure` when you need it

Comment: I like this suggestion however I was hoping that I could get the same performance elsewhere. If I can't I will use this though.

Comment: if you want that performance, make your function `static inline` in the header

Comment: Will static inline do the same sort of optimization as the pure attribute?

Comment: This is not allowed. You define the name `__pure`, which is a [reserved identifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers). `PURE` would work, though

Comment: @NicolasViennot Headers are expected to contain global symbols. Putting a namespace static declaration (internal symbol) in a header is absurd.

Answer (score 2):

I think the portable way is to inline the functions and hope the compiler will figure out the rest.